# read command with timeout for non-terminal input in bash

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

The `read` command in bash is used for user input. Option `-t N` invokes the timeout of N seconds. But, as mentioned in the man page,

> This option has no effect if read is not reading input from the
>   terminal or from a pipe.

But this is exactly what I need - I need a script that is launched via desktop shortcut (not from terminal), and should wait another second for a single key to decide further actions. How can I make bash script wait a bit for user input in this case?

Comment: User input is from the terminal, so your quoted extract is not relevant; it refers for example to running the script with input redirected to come from a file. You may need to use `bash /c ScriptFile` in your short-cut in order to make sure of seeing the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use timeout command before the read command.

```
Syntax:timeout [OPTION] NUMBER[SUFFIX] COMMAND [ARG]...
```